# JMeter save results to file

Tags: java, jmeter

In the JMeter GUI it is easy to add a listener such as 'View Results Tree' or 'View Results in Table' and add a file name

[image]

I have a method that creates and runs a test plan that looks like this

```
//JMeter Engine
StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

//JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/path/to/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/jmeter.properties");
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/path/to/apache-jmeter-4.0");
JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
JMeterUtils.initLocale();

// JMeter Test Plan, basic all u JOrphan HashTree
HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

// HTTP Sampler
HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
httpSampler.setDomain("example.com");
httpSampler.setPort(80);
httpSampler.setPath("/");
httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

// Loop Controller
LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
loopController.setLoops(1);
loopController.addTestElement(httpSampler);
loopController.setFirst(true);
loopController.initialize();


// Thread Group
ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

// Test Plan
TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");

// Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
testPlanTree.add("httpSampler", httpSampler);

// Run Test Plan
jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
jmeter.run();
```

1. is there a convenient premade test element to simple add to the thread group and save the results straight to a file (in the same way the 'View Results in Table' listener does from the gui).
2. what does implementing a listener that would do this task look like

EDIT: I added the changes using ResultCollector and it successfully saved the file data.csv However, it only created csv column names but never created any results.

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");//$NON-NLS-1$
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}

ResultCollector rc = new ResultCollector(summer);
rc.setFilename("C:\\Users\\user\\data.csv");
rc.setErrorLogging(true);

threadGroup.addTestElement(rc);
testPlanTree.add("rc", rc);
```

My full output looks like this

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Apr 16, 2018 1:40:32 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5. summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)`
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines from your code:

```
threadGroup.addTestElement(rc);
testPlanTree.add("rc", rc);
```

and substitute it with the following:

```
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], rc);
```

Also be aware that if you leave this line:

```
rc.setErrorLogging(true);
```

you will have **only errors** in your .jtl results file.

I also fail to see any sampler executed so double check your test plan using following reference material:

- [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code)

Comment: Still the same results. I am actually trying to run a javasampler but I have shared using an httpsampler. Am I not using the HttpSampler correctly here?

Comment: I have updated my post with the full output at the bottom. I am wondering if the error or warning that is printed needs to be solved for jmeter to work?